# Packages installed through "conda install" on Anaconda Prompt not listed in the package list for the environment on Anaconda Navigator

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

As I am new to Anaconda, I recently installed Anaconda for Windows 64bit.

Following the documentation I managed to created a new environment via `conda create --name tensorflow python=3.7`. It came with 11 packages by default. Then I installed tensorflow as well as its associated packages.

[image]

On the Anaconda Navigator's package pane, there are still 11 packages listed for the tensorflow environment. It seams the package list was not properly updated with tensorflow environment.

[image]

Is there any step I missed to get it right?

Answer (score 0):

Too late, but for anyone passing by: "Update index" button in the Navigator helped me with similar issue (not seeing packages although installed thru Prompt).